# Why is my next.js code all seen as a string value?

Tags: html, json, string, next.js, syntax-error

the whole code after

```
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
```

(11th line down) is identified as a string value. this changes whenever i add a dash '/' anywhere along the code, only the next few lines of code after i add the dash become normal syntax, if i add another one along then the next few lines after that one only become normal syntax, and so on. Im trying to make a website with next.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header>
      <nav className="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
};

const About = () => {
  return (
    <section id="about" className="section">
      <h2 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>About Me</h2>
      <div className="content">
        <p style={{ color: '#fff', textAlign: 'center' }}>infromation</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

const Projects = () => {
  return (
    <section id="projects" className="section">
      <h2 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Projects</h2>
      <div className="content info-grid">
        <div className="info-box">
          <h3 style={{ color: '#fff', textAlign: 'center' }}>Project 1</h3>
          <p style={{ color: '#fff', textAlign: 'center' }}>infromation.</p>
        </div>
        <div className="info-box">
          <h3 style={{ color: '#fff', textAlign: 'center' }}>Project 2</h3>
          <p style={{ color: '#fff', textAlign: 'center' }}>infromation.</p>
        </div>
        <div className="info-box">
          <h3 style={{ color: '#fff', textAlign: 'center' }}>Project 3</h3>
          <p style={{ color: '#fff', textAlign: 'center' }}>infromation.</p>
        </div>
        {/* Add more projects*/}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

const Skills = () => {
  return (
    <section id="skills" className="section">
      <h2 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Skills</h2>
      <div className="content info-grid">
        <div className="info-box">
          <h3 style={{ color: '#fff', textAlign: 'center' }}>Coding</h3>
          <ul>
            <li style={{ color: '#fff' }}>Python</li>
            <li style={{ color: '#fff' }}>JavaScript</li>
            {/* Add more coding skills*/}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="info-box">
          <h3 style={{ color: '#fff', textAlign: 'center' }}>Robotics</h3>
          <ul>
            <li style={{ color: '#fff' }}>Robotic Systems</li>
            <li style={{ color: '#fff' }}>Control Systems</li>
            {/* Add more robotics skills*/}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="info-box">
          <h3 style={{ color: '#fff', textAlign: 'center' }}>Web Development</h3>
          <ul>
            <li style={{ color: '#fff' }}>HTML</li>
            <li style={{ color: '#fff' }}>CSS</li>
            <li style={{ color: '#fff' }}>JavaScript</li>
            {/* Add more web development skills*/}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

const Contact = () => {
  return (
    <section id="contact" className="section">
      <h2>Contact Me</h2>
      <div className="content">
        <p style={{ color: '#fff' }}>Feel free to reach out to me using the contact details below:</p>
        <ul>
          <li style={{ color: '#fff' }}>Email: example@example.com</li>
          <li style={{ color: '#fff' }}>Phone: 123-456-7890</li>
          {/* Add more contact details*/}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <footer>
      <p>&copy; 2023 All rights reserved.</p>
    <footer>
  );
};

const IndexPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      {/* Place other components here */}
      <About/>
      <Projects />
      <Skills />
      <Contact />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default IndexPage;
```

if i add a dash after `<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>` (marked below), then the 9 lines below it turn from string variable to their normal syntax.

```
import React from 'react';

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header>
      <nav className="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
>           <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>**/**
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
};

const About = () => {
  return (
    <section id="about" className="section">
      <h2 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>About Me</h2>
      <div className="content">
        <p style={{ color: '#fff', textAlign: 'center' }}>infromation</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
```

this is the type of error for each body of text that i get,

```
 x Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'>'}` or `&gt;`?
     ,-[/Users/name/firstsite/app/page.js:108:1]
 108 |   );
 109 | };
 110 | 
 111 | const IndexPage = () => {
     :                       ^
 112 |   return (
 113 |     <div>
 114 |
```

it tells me 'did you mean >' when thats exactly whats there.